# Get all rows where column1=column1 and column2!=column2

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is it possible, in **Sqlite3**, `SELECT` all rows which has one attribute equal but another attribute not equal?

```
SELECT count(*),title,katalogove_cislo FROM records GROUP BY katalogove_cislo ORDER BY count(*)
```

For example this query returns grouped rows with equal `katalogove_cislo`. I want to exclude those groups, which has the same column `popis`.

So

```
id,katalogove_cislo,popis
1,444,xxx
2,444,xxx
3,555,xx
4,555,xx
6,555,xy
```

would return one group with `katalogove_cislo` - 555 because group 444 has equal column `popis`.

EDIT:

I try to make it more clear.

If I do group by katalogove_cislo, I get "groups" with the same katalogove_cislo. Each group can contain multiple rows with the same katalogove_cislo. I want to get only those groups, where at least one row has different title from other rows in the group.

```
id,katalogove_cislo,popis
1,444,xxx
2,444,xxx
3,555,xx
4,555,xx
6,555,xy
```

If I do group by katalogove_cislo on this table, I get 444 and 555. But, since rows from group with katalogove_cislo 444 has equal popis (xxx and xxx) I don't want to see this group. Second group with katalogove_cislo 555 hasn't same titles - xx == xx != xy , so I want to return this group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your updated question, this should work. This will eliminate records where there is only one *distinct* occurrence of the value in `popis`.

```
SELECT
    -- This returns the original values from the source table
    tb.id,
    tb.katalogove_cislo,
    tb.popis
FROM
    (
    -- This will return only values in katalogove_cislo where
    -- there are more than 1 distinct values in popis.
    SELECT
       katalogove_cislo,
       COUNT(DISTINCT popis) AS popis_count
    FROM
       records
    GROUP BY
       katalogove_cislo,
    HAVING
       COUNT(DISTINCT popis) > 1
    ) ta
INNER JOIN
    records tb
    ON (ta.katalogove_cislo = tb.katalogove_cislo)
```

Starting with this dataset:

```
id | katalogove_cislo | popis
-----------------------------
 1 |    444           | xxx
 2 |    444           | xxx
 3 |    555           | xx
 4 |    555           | xx
 5 |    555           | xy
```

The query should return:

```
id | katalogove_cislo | popis
-----------------------------
 3 |    555           | xx     
 4 |    555           | xx
 5 |    555           | xy
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. To be clear - I want to get rows under this condition: if there is a group of rows which has the same katalogove_cislo, then, if all these rows hasn't equal title, return the katalogove_cislo. So I want rows with the same katalogove_cislo but not same title.

Comment: @Milano - It is not 100% clear to me what you are asking. Can you update your post with some more information and detail around your table design and data?

Comment: I've tried to elaborate it more, please, check the botton of the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to check across all rows of a group, this you need to apply following logic:

```
SELECT
   count(*) AS cnt,
   katalogove_cislo
FROM
   records
GROUP BY
   katalogove_cislo
HAVING -- at least two different values
   MIN(popis) <> MAX(popis)
ORDER BY
   cnt
```